# How to Generate an ELContext without an active FacesContext?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I need to get access to EL functionality in a Servlet Filter, but... that means I am not within the FacesServlet lifecycle.

Thus, I need to instantiate an ELContext. I do not want to go down the road of instantiating a FacesContext, since that may cause issues when the application does forward to FacesServlet.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What do you need to get from the EL? Might be an easier way to get what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am writing a web-framework, there is no way to use a PhaseListener, this must be done inside the Servlet Filter.

However, I did find the solution in the Seam Solder (WeldX) CDI module - this only works when running on CDI.

http://docs.jboss.org/weld/extensions/reference/latest/en-US/html/elextensions.html

Answer (score 2):

Better use a `PhaseListener` instead of a `Filter`.

Comment: I checked into the ELContext spec... and it's only accessible if provided by either a JSP or JSF Context... so looks like I'd have to instantiated a FacesContext to get this working, which I am already doing but I really just don't like that route... I'll see if a PhaseListener can do what I need.

Comment: A PhaseListener is basically kind of JSF Filter which can intercept on the JSF lifecycle phases. In your case you likely need to listen on the `beforePhase` of the `RESTORE_VIEW`, which is the earlymost point to participate with the FacesContext.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it makes sense to do this. Within a JSP context, you would be able to resolve JSP artefacts; within a JSF context, you would be able to resolve JSF artefacts. In a `Filter`, these artefacts are not going to be available to you.

If you just want to resolve expressions against objects you define, it is possible to [create your own context](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/04/java-using-el-outside-j2ee.html) (you may need to know the platform's `ExpressionFactory` class if you also want to create expressions).

There is probably a better way to achieve whatever it is you are doing, such as [BalusC's suggestion of a PhaseListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677555/how-to-generate-an-elcontext-without-an-active-facescontext/1677650#1677650).

Comment: I like this possibility, but I think it's too much extra code for what I need to do. I'll just live within Faces :(